# .Net Framework 4 project using X86 DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a .Net project built in VS2010 compiling against .Net 4 that uses an older 32 bit dll.  The project will be deployed to a Windows 2008 64 bit server where the dll used is registered in SYSWOW64 and is being used by other legacy programs.  I had an issue with it that was solved by changing the platform target to X86 on the build tab in the project properties.  Initially, I compiled the project and the dll in question is copied to the bin folder.  To test, I copied the release folder to the server desktop and the program runs fine.  However, if I set the copy local to false the dll is not included in bin - as expected, but the program no longer runs on the server.  The development environment is XP service pack 3.

Why can't the program find and use the registered copy of the dll in SYSWOW64?

Comment: What is the erros ? have you checked if the module was located and its dependencies? Use [Depends.Net](http://www.netomatix.com/development/DependsNet.aspx)

Comment: @lsalamon, it is giving a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.  I'll try Depends.net as you suggest.

Comment: @lsalamon - no luck with depends.net.  It can't open the dll or the exe